# Spread to create new object for array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've tried to spread my array of object to create a new object but instead destroying the previous object

this is how I tried to spread my array

```js
const currentArraySlug = [
  {
    slug: "jagung-com", content_viewed: [1, 2], all_viewed: false
  }
]

const newSlug = {
  slug: "New slug",
  content_viewed: [],
  all_viewed: false
}

const mergeData = Object.assign({}, newSlug, ...(currentArraySlug))

console.log(mergeData);
```

This is my Expected output

```
[
  {
    slug: "jagung-com",
    content_viewed: [1, 2],
    all_viewed: false
  },
  {
    slug: "New slug",
    content_viewed: [],
    all_viewed: false
  }
]
```

How can I deal with it, Thanks in advance

Comment: `const mergeData = currentArraySlug.concat(newSlug)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to merge data with spread operation is as below

```js
const currentArraySlug = [
  {
    slug: "jagung-com", content_viewed: [1, 2], all_viewed: false
  }
]

const newSlug = {
  slug: "New slug",
  content_viewed: [],
  all_viewed: false
}

const mergeData = [newSlug, ...currentArraySlug];

console.log(mergeData);
```